# Issues with new node bootstrap

Tags: cassandra

We are using Cassandra 3.11.2 and when trying to bootstrap a new node, the streaming takes a lot of time. The cluster is a three node one, and we are in the process of adding the fourth one. The data available on the other three nodes is close to 190GB, and the instance size is 5 core, 5GB running on spinning drives.

`nodetool netstats` on the new node says streaming files, and of 106 files, 15 received from node A.  But same `netstats` on node A claims all 106 files have been sent.

Also, we were running into some keep alive related issues and we did increase the same on the new node. This is our second attempt, and in the first attempt, the bootstrap kept failing, and we either resume it or restart the Cassandra on the new node, and the data grew close to 500GB, and then compaction happened and came down to 236GB.

But then bootstrap kept failing. So we discarded it and started fresh again. This time, as suggested in the hardware choices doc, we went with a different physical disk for commit log and data to see if iops was the issue.

And the process never ends. Meaning, it fails in-between with connection reset by peer or IO exception and we have been struggling with this for almost a week now.

How much do you think it ideally takes for bootstrapping a node with data close to 190GB? Any advice/suggestions would be of great help. 
The new node is started with auto_bootstrap flag set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How much do you think it ideally takes for bootstrapping a node with data close to 190GB?

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to answer this.  A lot of factors go into determining how quickly new nodes will bootstrap, essentially being very specific to the underlying infra.

> We are using Cassandra 3.11.2

I recommend upgrading (at least) to 3.11.4.  It's a simple binary upgrade that does not require running a `nodetool upgradesstables`.  The reason, is that 3.11.4 has a feature which allows failed bootstrapping to resume where it left off.  At least then, you won't have to completely start over each time.

> data grew close to 500GB, and then compaction happened and came down to 236GB.

So there are some reasons that this can happen.  Are the rack definitions (cassandra-rackdc.properties) the same or different?  If you're bootstrapping the node as a new logical rack, you might see the one new node being responsible for owning 100% of available token ranges.  Whereas, if you join a new node with the same logical rack as the others, the ownership percentage (and disk footprint) will go down.

> Any advice/suggestions would be of great help.

I've encountered issues like this as well, when bootstrapping nodes into new physical data centers. One thing that I've had success with, was setting `auto_bootstrap: false` and running a `nodetool rebuild` to stream from the remote DC.  Of course, if you don't have another DC to stream from, that's not going to work.

You could also start the node without bootstrapping enabled, and run a `nodetool repair` once it comes up.  This has some drawbacks in that the new node will still try to serve client requests, regardless of whether or not it actually has the data.  But it would let you at least get the node joined, and stream the data over on a more gradual basis.

That's why **upgrading to 3.11.4** is probably your best option.  Then you can restart the node when the streams fail, it'll pick up where it left off, and it won't take client requests until data streaming completes.